# PySpark JDBC Teradata Connection

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, teradata

I submit spark jobs with `spark-submit` and specify the latest verison of Teradata JDBC Driver (17.10.00.14) to load via the `--jars` flag. The logs confirm that the JAR file is added successfully.

However, when making a connection to Teradata with

```py
(
  spark.read.format("jdbc").
    option("url", url).
    option("user", user).
    option("password", password).
    option("dbtable", table)
)
```

get the error: `Invalid connection parameter name dbtable`.
This `java.sql.SQLException` is thrown by the `com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4` library.

Logically, if I remove `dbtable` from the options

```py
(
  spark.read.format("jdbc").
    option("url", url).
    option("user", user).
    option("password", password).
    option("dbtable", table)
)
```

I get another error: `Option 'dbtable' or 'query' is required`.
This `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown by `pyspark`.

My understanding is that there is an incompatibility between Spark 3.1.1 and Teradata JDBC Driver 17.10.00.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading the Teradata JDBC Driver to 17.00.00.03 solved the problem, which is evidence for the incompatibility of the mentioned versions.

Update: Per @Tom Nolan's response, the issue is rooted in PySpark's API design and they should be updating their JDBC wrapper.

Comment: It seems that Spark is leaving the dbtable option in the Properties object passed to the JDBC driver. Older versions of the Teradata JDBC driver expected options to be in the url string but (according to the ReadMe) as of 17.10.00.06 options can be supplied in either Properties or in url text. Throwing an error for invalid options in the url has been in place since 16.00.00.26

Comment: I have only included options in the properties (as options) and never in the url. I'm doing the same for the 17.00 version. So, the README might be a bit misleading. I've seen older posts suggesting to include in the options.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of the Teradata JDBC Driver before version 17.10.00.06 only examined the "user" and "password" properties, and ignored all the other properties that might have been specified in the Properties object.

Beginning with Teradata JDBC Driver 17.10.00.06, all the properties in the Properties object are validated and used.

That is the explanation for the behavior difference between the old and new versions of the Teradata JDBC Driver.

You must avoid specifying properties like "dbtable" in the Properties object that are not valid connection parameters for the Teradata JDBC Driver.

You must only specify valid connection parameters for the Teradata JDBC Driver in the Properties object. If you specify any properties like "dbtable" that are not valid Teradata JDBC Driver connection parameters, then Teradata JDBC Driver 17.10.00.06 and later will throw an exception "Invalid connection parameter name".

That is the intended and expected behavior for Teradata JDBC Driver 17.10.00.06 and later.

EDIT Aug 16, 2021

We just published Teradata JDBC Driver 17.10.00.20, which offers a new connection parameter STRICT_NAMES=OFF (the default is ON). When you specify STRICT_NAMES=OFF, then the Teradata JDBC Driver will ignore invalid connection parameter names, rather than throw an exception.

Please note that connection parameters specified in the Properties argument for the DriverManager.getConnection method take precedence over connection parameters specified in the JDBC connection URL. If the same connection parameter name is specified in both places, then the connection parameter value from the Properties argument will be used. That is also true for the STRICT_NAMES connection parameter.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the second part of the question where "removing dbtable" would throw an exception by PySpark? The main concern of my question is around the incompatibility of a JDBC version and PySpark version; hence my answer below as to why I downgraded.

Comment: Spark should distinguish between its own properties "dbtable" and "query" versus JDBC driver properties. Spark should avoid passing its own "dbtable" and "query"  properties to the JDBC driver.